# How do I toggle if a double is negative or not?

Tags: java, double, toggle

I'm new to java, and i'm trying to create an android app were you can tilt your device to rotate an imageview. I've got everything, except that the imageview is rotating the wrong direction. So if the number in my double is > 0, I want to put a - in front of it. But if it's < 0, I want to remove the - that is in front of it. I've tried to do it like this:

Here is the variables:

```
double xaxis;
String xaxis3;
```

And here is my code:

```
if (xaxis < 0) {
        xaxis3 = Double.toString(xaxis);
        xaxis3 = xaxis3.replaceAll("-", "");
        double xaxis = Double.parseDouble(xaxis3);
    }

    else {
        xaxis3 = Double.toString(xaxis);
        xaxis3 = ("-" + xaxis3);
        double xaxis = Double.parseDouble(xaxis3);
    }
```

Please be nice to me and think of that i'm new to programming. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I have taken the liberty of editing your question title to remove extraneous tagging.  See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/136378)

Answer (score 6):

Um, I think you want:

```
xaxis = -xaxis;
```

But it's not clear why you're using a string representation at all... avoid string conversions unless you actually *need* them.

Additionally, declaring a new *local* variable which shadows an *instance* variable, and doing so at the end of a block, isn't going to be useful:

```
... {
    xaxis3 = Double.toString(xaxis);
    xaxis3 = ("-" + xaxis3);
    double xaxis = Double.parseDouble(xaxis3);
}
```

You need to be careful about things like this - although I'd expect a good IDE to warn you about an unused local variable in this case, and hopefully the duplicate name too.

Comment: I suppose the string representation is only to add/remove the `-` character.

Comment: @Fls'Zen: Possibly - in which case it can be removed entirely.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
xaxis3 = Double.toString(-xaxis);
```

or

```
String your_string = "" + (-xaxis);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achieve, but if you don't want to cross axis X boundaries, this is what you need:

```
if(xaxis < 0 || xaxis > MAX_AXIS_X) {
    xaxis = -xaxis;
}
```